# Asp.Net membership provider conflict

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

this is my membership provider

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
             connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             requiresUniqueEmail="true"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
             passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

when i expand the membership provider using the quickwatch the membership provider is "AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" which i cant find anywhere in my web.config and cant find where to make the changes.

**UPDATE**

This is a MVC4 Wep app template from VS2012.  I am not using the views, i am developing an API using WebApi.

So I am accessing everything through the controller.  I am running unit test to test the controllers and when I try to create a new user I am seeing that the membership is not configured provider I have in the web.config

**ERROR UPDATE**

Result Message: 
Test method *.TestUserControllerPost threw exception: 
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\App_Data' is denied.

that is the error message i got which lead me to investigate the membership providers and connection string.  Then i realized it was using the default I configured, but configuration which thinks the DB is local.

I am getting this error when running the unit test.

**When I run the project normally and make the normal GET call to the controller it works fine**

Comment: Why the heck are you developing your app inside Program Files?

Comment: I am not developing it inside program file!! This error is only happening when I run the unit test in the test project.  This is my first test project so i am sure y the configuration is changing vs when i run it normally

Comment: Unit tests don't typically use membership, you need to wrap your membership calls in a testable object

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change the `MembershipProvider` property of the `Login` control you are using and set it to the name of this provider: `DefaultMembershipProvider`.

If that's not what the problem is could you please post some more info about where/what error you are getting?

Comment: I have never experienced this before not sure info to add.  there are no login controls anywhere in the project

Comment: Surely you must be getting an error of some sort though, to prompt you to ask 'the question'? Maybe describe the behaviour you want to get, and what you are getting instead.